# Adding weighted lists together

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I have two lists. (Csv files, 300x300)
The values in list A have to be muliplied by 2.4
The values in list B have to be multiplied by 0.2
Then each the values at each corresponding position must be mulitiplied by each other so:

G =(listA * 2.4)*(listB * 0.2)

```
ListC = []

For i in range (len(listA)): 
    For j in range (len(listA[i])):                                     
        Weight1 = listA[i][j] * 2.4     
    ListC.append(weight1)
```

I've then done the same for list B, but appending it to listD. Is this the correct way to do it? How would i then multiply every corresponding position in listC and listD?

Comment: Do you have one nested list or two separate flat lists or two nested lists? It’s unclear to me what the structure of your input data is. It would help if you showed a small but representative example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your own example seems like you have nested lists, but in answer to your actual question:

> The values in list A have to be muliplied by 2.4 The values in list B have to be multiplied by 0.2 Then each the values at each corresponding position must be mulitiplied by each other so:

You could do it pretty neatly with this:

```py
list_c = []
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    list_c.append((a * 2.4) * (b * 0.5))
```

Or even more compact (if you're into that sort of thing) with list comprehension:

```py
list_c = [(a * 2.4) * (b * 0.5) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

A sidenote: avoid using capital letters for variable (and function) names. It's not very [pythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).